# How to navigate a datagrid using key presses?

Tags: c#, datagrid, navigation

It seems to me I remember that my DataGrid was once able to take me to the first row of a sorted column with the text starting with the same letter as a pressed key, i.e. type 'k' and the cursor would be located at the row with 'Kenny' as the contents. I don't know if I've accidently disabled this property or am confusing this feature with my treeview which navigates this way already.  Is there a property I've inadvertently disabled?  Also, what is the official term for this feature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built in feature to do this in the DataGrid class. I have found that overriding the OnKeyDown or OnKeyPress of the Datagrid class can simulate this pretty easily.

`
class NavDataGrid : System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs ke)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(ke);
            //handle navigation here
        }
    }

`